# How to add Actioned(User Defined) Variable in Content Approval Status

Tags: sharepoint-designer, office-365

I want to add a new variable Actioned in content approval apart from Pending, Approved, Rejected.

If not I need to edit Content Approval Variables to Pending and Actioned.

Is there any feasiblity in Sharepoint Desingner2013 or Office365

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a task list for your approvals?  If so, you can use the sharepoint website to go to list options, and edit any field options of any of your lists.  So if you have a field that has Pending, Approved, and Rejected, you can add in any other option you'd like.